# How to add span & inside that control dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add span & inside that span I want to add control.

Both have to be added dynamically using code in c#.

I know how to add span but how to add control inside that span ?

Code to add span & control are

```
var a = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
a.InnerHtml = "Something";
a.Attributes["class"] = "validation-asterix";
pn.Controls.Add(a);

RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator {
                        ControlToValidate = "txt" + txField.ColumnName,
                        Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
                        Text = "*",
                        ID = "val" + txField.ColumnName,
                        Visible = true,
                     };
pn.Controls.Add(rfv);
```

I want to add above span which will have this requiredfieldvalidator dynamically.

Comment: do you want to put a required field validator for a span element?

Comment: I think I do not understand your point...

Comment: Yes I want to put requiredfieldvalidator inside span element & both should be generated dynamically.

Comment: But what is `"txt" + txField.ColumnName`? Why it is necessary to put the validator inside a `span`? I do not think that it will be the most valid approach...

Comment: "txt" + txField.ColumnName is data coming from database. as per my design I have to put requiredfieldvalidator inside span.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do is to create a void `ContentPlaceHolder` in the markup code, in the place that you want to show the validation error message.

Then, from codebehind, you simply can add the validator as:

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator {
                    ID = "val" + txField.ColumnName,
                    ControlToValidate = "txt" + txField.ColumnName,
                    Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
                    Text = "*",
                    CssClass = "validation-asterix"
                 };
ContentPlaceHolderID.Controls.Add(rfv);
```

Not need to use any `span` here.